# How to move a pod from one node to another in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod P1 that located in Node N1. I need to move that to another Node N2. What are the different ways to do this other than node selector?

nodeSelector:
name: N1

Comment: Why do you need to move it, or manually place it at all?  Is there any programming-related aspect to this or is it just about cluster configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you cannot “move” a pod from one node to another. You can only delete it from one node and have it re-created on another. To delete use the kubectl delete command. To ensure a pod lands on a specific node using node affinity/taints and tolerations. Hope that helps.

[please see this Answer](https://kodekloud.com/community/t/hi-how-to-manually-move-pods-from-one-worker-node-to-another-node/22386)

Comment: Is that the reference?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer mentioned, you cannot move pods but you can configure them to come up on specific nodes.

See official docs on [assigning pods to nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/), [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) and [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/)

Answer (score 0):

use nodeName:  aligned with the containers attribute to make sure that the pod runs on a particular node. Like others have indicated, you have to delete the pod first and recreate it and nodeName would send it to the node you want it to run on.